# Is my solution to Rudin's PMA, Q18, Chapter 2 wrong?

Tags: real-analysis

The question asks us whether its possible to form a non-empty perfect set with only the irrationals

https://artofproblemsolving.com/downloads/printable_post_collections/435660

One solution i have found is as above, it uses something similar to the construction of the cantor set by removing all rationals in a interval with irrational endpoints to get a perfect non-empty compact set. I understand this solution and the other solution(https://linearalgebras.com/baby-rudin-chapter-2b.html) i could find online uses a similar approach so im guessing my solution is wrong but im not quite sure why.

In the preceding question(baby rudin chapter 2 q17 which solution is also in the above link), we were asked to show whether E, the set of all $x \in [0,1]$ whose decimals only contain $4$ and $7$ is countable? Whether E is dense in $[0,1]$? Whether E is compact? Whether E is perfect? Given that I have solved that and found that such a set E would be perfect, would it be valid to just form a set $H={x+\pi:x\in E }$ as a solution to the question? Such a set would clearly only contain irrationals and the pf of it being perfect would be almost identical to that of set $E$. Could anyone either help me check whether such a solution is valid or if not, how it would fail?

Edit: resolved, the reason it fails is because $E$ contains irrationals since it's an uncountable subset of the real numbers, and the sum of two irrationals could be rational, thus the set H I have created may contain rationals.

Comment: why do u assume that H only contains irrational numbers?

Comment: Okay thank you, I got it now. I thought the sum of any real number with irrational could only be an irrational which is clearly wrong now that I think about it.